# coproduct, topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let I be a set and for every $i\in I$ let $X_i$ be a topological space. We define the coproduct as follows:
>
> $X=\coprod_{i\in I} X_i:=\{(i,x)\in I\times\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i\right)|x\in X_i\}$
>
> and we define $f_i:X_i\to X$ through $f_i(x)=(i,x)$. Also we say, that $U\supseteq X$ open iff $f_i^{-1}(U)\subseteq X_i$ open for every $i\in I$.
>
> a) This defines a topology $\tau$ on $X$
>
> b) Every $f_i: X_i\to X$ is continuous.

Hello,

I have a question to this task. I want to show, that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.

1)

$\emptyset\in\tau$ and $X\in\tau$

$f_i^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset\subseteq X_i$ is open, since $X_i$ is a topological space. Hence $\emptyset\subseteq X$ is open.

$f_i^{-1}(X)=X_i$ which is open in $X_i$. Hence $X\subseteq X$ is open.

2)

For $U,V\in\tau$ is $U\cap V\in\tau$.

Let $U,V$ be open sets in $X$. Therefore $f_i^{-1}(U), f_i^{-1}(V)$ are open sets in $X_i$ for every $i\in I$.

$f_i^{-1}(U)\cap f_i^{-1}(V)=f_i^{-1}(U\cap V)\subseteq X_i$ is open. Hence $U\cap V\subseteq X$ is open.

3)

For $\mathcal{U}\subseteq\tau$ is $\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}} U\in\tau$.

For every $U\in\mathcal{U}$ is $f_i^{-1}(U)$ open.
Hence $\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}} f_i^{-1}(U)=f_i^{-1}(\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}} U)$ open.

Therefor $\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}} U\in\tau$

Now I want to show, that every function $f_i: X_i\to X$ is continuous.
This follows immediatly from the definition of $\tau$.

I have to show, that the preimage of an open set, is an open set.

$U\subseteq X$ open $\Leftrightarrow\quad f_i^{-1}(U)\subseteq X_i$ open, for every $i\in I$.

> c) Let $Y$ be an additional topological space and let $h_i: X_i\to Y$ be continuous functions.
> Then exists an uniquely determined contiuous function $h: X\to Y$ with $h\circ f_i=h_i$

I tried this:

The existence of such a function $h$ should be clear. You could choose $h=id$.
I am not sure how to prove that this function is unique.
I did it like this:

Suppose $h,g: X\to Y$ are continuous functions with $h\circ f_i=h_i$ and $g\circ f_i=h_i$. Then

$h\circ f_i(x)=h((i,x))=h_i(x)=g\circ f_i(x)$

Hence $h=g$

Would this be enough?
Am I wrong at any point?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for (1), (2) are correct.

Your answer for (3) is a little off. You claim, "you could take $h = \mathrm{id}$, but that is (almost never) true. Note, $h$ should be a function $X \to Y$. Once you decide the correct definition of $h$, it should not be too hard to show that it is unique.

Comment: Is there any approach to this, that can help finding the correct definition of $h$? What about $h: X\to Y$ with $h((i,x))=y_i$.

Comment: Maybe $h((i,x))=h_i(x)$ is a better approach. Since $h_i(x)\in Y$

Comment: @Siu, yes, that is correct! Do you see why? And can you prove that $h$ is unique?

Comment: When I try to prove it, how do I start? Do I assume that I have two functions, $h$ and $g$ that do exactly the same? Hence $h(i,x)=h_i(x)$ and $g(i,x)=h_i(x)$?

Comment: That would already be a proof that they are equal. In fact, what you assume is that you have $h,g$ that both satisfy the conditions you asked for: namely, $h \circ f_i = h_i$ and $g \circ f_i = h_i$.

Comment: Ok, suppose that. We get $h(f_i(x))=h((i,x))=h_i(x)=g\circ f_i(x)=g((i,x))$. Hence $h=g$

Comment: Exactly! Although I would have written the equalities in a different order.

Comment: Can you show me how a professional would write this down? :) Do I not have to show, that my defined $h$ is continuous?